# How to make gnuplot pm3d map fill the area?

Tags: gnuplot

I am plotting a heatmap with data that range from 0-60 degrees and 0-1 in r-axis. i have data for angles 0-60 with a step 5, but not all the r-axis data is till 1, so the plot as shown in the image dosent fill the area, i tried to use dgrid3d but it gives a square instead of a pie. i tried to use table but it give the same output. anyway to solve this issue
[The image with dgrid3d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYpxX.png)

[image without dgrid3d](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sb5m5.png)

```
reset

set term pngcairo enhanced size 800,800
set output 'polar.png'

set angles degrees

set multiplot

set lmargin at screen 0.1
set tmargin at screen 0.9
set rmargin at screen 0.9
set bmargin at screen 0.1

set samples 1000
unset border


set pm3d interpolate 10,10
set pm3d map
unset key
#set dgrid3d #20,20
unset xtics
unset ytics
# plot the heatmap
set parametric
set isosamples 15
set style data lines
set yrange[0:1]
set xrange[0:1]

set colorbox user origin 0.9,0.1 size 0.03,0.8
set dgrid3d
#set mapping spherical

splot 'file2' u 1:2:3 w pm3d
#splot 'file' u ($2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):3 w pm3d

unset parametric




R_max = 1
dR = 0.2

phi_max = 60.
dphi = 15

set xr [0:R_max]
set yr [0:R_max]

set xtics out nomirror
unset ytics

set style line 42 lc rgb '#666666' dt 3

unset key
plot \
    for [i=0:phi_max/dphi] (x>=0&&x<=R_max*cos(i*dphi))?tan(i*dphi)*x:1/0 w l ls 42

set polar
set trange [0:phi_max]
unset raxis
unset rtics
plot \
    for [i=1:ceil(R_max/dR)] i*dR<=R_max?i*dR:1/0 w l ls 42

unset raxis
unset rtics
#plot cos(t) w l lw 2 lc rgb 'dark-red'
unset polar


unset multiplot
```

Data
this data is in polar, the ones i used in my code(file2) are in Cartesian.

```
000       0.000000    -567.843749
000       0.050000    -568.242741
000       0.100000    -569.396028
000       0.150000    -570.983598
000       0.200000    -572.176873
000       0.250000    -572.424322
000       0.300000    -572.153335
000       0.350000    -571.252885
000       0.400000    -570.257285
000       0.450000    -569.615631
000       0.500000    -569.014787
000       0.550000    -568.421221
000       0.600000    -568.063772
000       0.650000    -567.922780
000       0.700000    -567.649734
000       0.750000    -566.979396
000       0.800000    -565.854379
000       0.850000    -564.367443
000       0.900000    -562.633771

005       0.050000    -568.242889
005       0.100000    -569.395867
005       0.150000    -570.975623
005       0.200000    -572.153443
005       0.250000    -572.379270
005       0.300000    -572.047221
005       0.350000    -571.064401
005       0.400000    -569.312097
005       0.450000    -569.761971
005       0.500000    -569.360536
005       0.550000    -568.901985
005       0.600000    -568.494190
005       0.650000    -568.153150
005       0.700000    -567.776895
005       0.750000    -567.096332
005       0.800000    -566.072266
005       0.850000    -564.744507

010       0.050000    -568.243316
010       0.100000    -569.395572
010       0.150000    -570.956890
010       0.200000    -572.081486
010       0.250000    -572.247407
010       0.300000    -571.749792
010       0.350000    -570.741542
010       0.400000    -570.087975
010       0.450000    -570.254711
010       0.500000    -570.187145
010       0.550000    -569.989762
010       0.600000    -569.483993
010       0.650000    -568.655762

015       0.050000    -568.243984
015       0.100000    -569.395407
015       0.150000    -570.938002
015       0.200000    -571.945605
015       0.250000    -572.032823
015       0.300000    -571.297522
015       0.350000    -570.294039
015       0.400000    -570.095426
015       0.450000    -570.639548
015       0.500000    -570.682988
015       0.550000    -570.298701
015       0.600000    -569.350864
015       0.650000    -567.896675
015       0.700000    -565.833766

020       0.050000    -568.244835
020       0.100000    -569.395274
020       0.150000    -570.926579
020       0.200000    -571.850254
020       0.250000    -571.749187
020       0.300000    -570.846381
020       0.350000    -569.954471
020       0.400000    -570.237205
020       0.450000    -570.703855
020       0.500000    -570.491711
020       0.550000    -569.690721
020       0.600000    -568.205663
020       0.650000    -566.100154

025       0.050000    -568.245790
025       0.100000    -569.394635
025       0.150000    -570.923898
025       0.200000    -571.822084
025       0.250000    -571.574220
025       0.300000    -570.540497
025       0.350000    -569.960901
025       0.400000    -570.371570
025       0.450000    -570.463930
025       0.500000    -569.595669
025       0.550000    -568.019734
025       0.600000    -565.702992
025       0.650000    -562.855754
025       0.700000    -560.472461
025       0.750000    -559.332584
025       0.800000    -558.249766
025       0.850000    -556.612031
025       0.900000    -554.217604

030       0.050000    -568.246776
030       0.100000    -569.392797
030       0.150000    -570.926246
030       0.200000    -571.851255
030       0.250000    -571.527200
030       0.300000    -570.550256
030       0.350000    -570.353883
030       0.400000    -570.438952
030       0.450000    -569.852769
030       0.500000    -568.044623
030       0.550000    -565.304218
030       0.600000    -562.191070
030       0.650000    -559.844770
030       0.700000    -558.834067
030       0.750000    -557.734881
030       0.800000    -555.870408

035       0.050000    -568.247721
035       0.100000    -569.389263
035       0.150000    -570.928035
035       0.200000    -571.916231
035       0.250000    -571.647586
035       0.300000    -570.975098
035       0.350000    -570.924148
035       0.400000    -570.422056
035       0.450000    -568.919994
035       0.500000    -566.055844
035       0.550000    -562.300180
035       0.600000    -559.270218
035       0.650000    -557.764774
035       0.700000    -556.502907
035       0.750000    -554.553016
035       0.800000    -551.554084
035       0.850000    -547.880991

040       0.050000    -568.248563
040       0.100000    -569.384018
040       0.150000    -570.925230
040       0.200000    -571.994284
040       0.250000    -571.960612
040       0.300000    -571.695707
040       0.350000    -571.544393
040       0.400000    -570.327361
040       0.450000    -567.805822
040       0.500000    -563.953571
040       0.550000    -559.789356
040       0.600000    -557.212857
040       0.650000    -555.764468
040       0.700000    -553.770274
040       0.750000    -550.829044
040       0.800000    -547.216866
040       0.850000    -543.689697
040       0.900000    -539.363981
040       0.950000    -534.483057

045       0.050000    -568.249254
045       0.100000    -569.377687
045       0.150000    -570.917089
045       0.200000    -572.088135
045       0.250000    -572.417978
045       0.300000    -572.478210
045       0.350000    -572.131353
045       0.400000    -570.198676
045       0.450000    -566.695529
045       0.500000    -562.125787
045       0.550000    -558.065435
045       0.600000    -555.749353
045       0.650000    -553.916710
045       0.700000    -551.207385
045       0.750000    -547.893803
045       0.800000    -545.014494
045       0.850000    -541.093878
045       0.900000    -536.385819
045       0.950000    -531.040665

050       0.050000    -568.249767
050       0.100000    -569.371485
050       0.150000    -570.905541
050       0.200000    -572.204233
050       0.250000    -572.938403
050       0.300000    -573.153207
050       0.350000    -572.585452
050       0.400000    -570.088330
050       0.450000    -565.800319
050       0.500000    -560.870216
050       0.550000    -557.064295
050       0.600000    -554.736681
050       0.650000    -552.435577
050       0.700000    -549.233344

055       0.050000    -568.250080
055       0.100000    -569.366904
055       0.150000    -570.894537
055       0.200000    -572.318129
055       0.250000    -573.325109
055       0.300000    -573.626528
055       0.350000    -572.829982
055       0.400000    -569.968184
055       0.450000    -565.255132
055       0.500000    -560.212112
055       0.550000    -556.598939
055       0.600000    -554.117709

060       0.050000    -568.250182
060       0.100000    -569.365204
060       0.150000    -570.889763
060       0.200000    -572.370609
060       0.250000    -573.450258
060       0.300000    -573.788501
060       0.350000    -572.907754
060       0.400000    -569.916464
060       0.450000    -565.078291
060       0.500000    -560.017199
060       0.550000    -556.469533
```

Comment: Its hard to help without having your data file for testing. `dgrid3d` always creates a rectangular grid. So you must probably do something like `set dgrid3d; set table 'tmp.dat'; splot 'file2' u 1:2:3; unset table; unset dgrid3d; set pm3d; splot 'tmp.dat' u ($2*cos($1)):($2*sin($1)):3`. That should fill the area, but I don't know how correct the interpolation of dgrid3d will be if you apply it before the transformation.

Comment: @christoph i added the data, i will try your method.